# Qt: Weird Behaviour when removing outline from QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to remove the dotted outline, when an item in a QTableView is focused. I found in other answers, that `outline: 0` will remove it, but i for me, that is only working in weird cases:

With this Stylesheet, the outline is removed and the background is yellow:

```cpp
tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item::focus { outline: 0; background-color: yellow; } QTableView { outline: 0; }");
```

With this Stylesheet the outline is still shown:

```cpp
tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item::focus { outline: 0; } QTableView { outline: 0; }");  
tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView { outline: 0; }");
tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item::focus { outline: 0; }");
tableView->setStyleSheet("QTableView::item::focus { outline: 0; background-color: yellow; }");
```

I want to have the outline removed and the background in its default color. But it seems, it's not having the option to. The outline command only works in specific cases, which feel very random to me.

Is this an error from me, in misunderstanding Qt or Stylesheets. Or is this a known bug, or a new bug?

Edit (images for understanding what i mean):

1. This is the default behaviour. See the outline around the element 1-2!
   [image: Default Behaviour]
2. This is with the style `QTableView::item::focus { outline: 0; background-color: yellow; } QTableView { outline: 0; }` added. Now the ouline is not shown, but the background of the focused object is yellow:
   [image: Working example]
3. This is with the 4 variants, that should work, but the outline is still shown (outline is around the object in position 1-2):
   [image: Failing example 1]
   [image: Failing example 2]
   [image: Failing example 3]
   [image: Failing example 4]

The thing is, i don't understand, why it works in exacly one specific way and not in the other ones?
And what do i have to do, to remove the outline without changing the background?

Comment: Say *What does not work:* It does not help to understand you, explain yourself better.

Comment: Note that loaded [style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) have to support style sheet to make this work. On each platform different style is used. So what is you platform/style?